# Downloading file using webclient with a save dialogue box

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I have one doubt, in my website i have to give an option for the front end users to download an exe from my website with a progress bar.

So can i use webClient.DownloadFile()?

But when i use

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://xyztest.com/xyztest.exe"), "xyztest.exe");
```

then the exe is saving to my website's folder path.

I want to save the file with a save dialogue box and with a progress bar. Please give your suggestions.

Thanks,

Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition: Attachment;` of the xyztest.exe.

Then just specify the url in the browser after the user accepts and it will download automatically.

Comment: This allows the user to continue doing whatever they were doing instead of waiting foTr your executable to download